# Proof for subtheories using compactness theorem

Tags: proof-verification, logic, model-theory

I'm trying to understand the use of the Compactness Theorem to proof certain properties for theories in languages. I've tried to prove the following:

If $\phi$ holds in every model of the theory $T$, then there is a finite subtheory $T'$ such that $\phi$ holds in every model of $T'$.

My proof is:

Because $\phi$ holds in $T$, $T \cup \{\neg \phi\}$ is an inconsistent theory. Compactness theorem then says that there is a finite subtheory of this theory that is inconsistent. This theory will be of the from $T' \cup \{\neg \phi\}$ with $T'$ a finite subtheory of $T$. Because $T' \cup \{\neg \phi\}$  is inconsistent, $\phi$ holds in every model of $T'$.

I'm not too sure if this proof is true, especially the part where I take the inconsistent finite subtheory.

Comment: Your inconsistent finite subtheory could be of the form $T'$, without the $\{\neg \phi\}$ - you need to rule out this case.

Comment: @B.Mehta: No, you don't.

Comment: If T is consistent, this is ruled out becaue of compactness theorem. What if T is inconsistent?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you explain where I'm mistaken?

Comment: @B.Mehta: If $T'$ is a subset of $T$, then $T$ is inconsistent and has no models. The statement holds vacuously.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, and I meant that OP should include that single line in their proof.

Comment: @B.Mehta: Why? Do you also include base case for strong induction?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Simply because this is where OP was unsure if that step was correct, and that line justifies the step clearly.

Comment: I don't really understand why the statement then holds vacuously.

Comment: @B.Mehta: Being unsure is one thing, and that's good to be able and practice spotting possible weak points in the proof. But adding unnecessary parts to the proof is not always the answer.

Comment: @xzeo: If $T$ has no models, then *all* the models of $T$ satisfy both $\phi$ and its negation.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair enough, perhaps I should instead have explained why that step was valid instead of suggesting a hint leading to the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Godel's completeness theorem. If $\phi$ is a statement true in every structure, then $\phi$ is a theorem of $T$ and so $\phi$ has a finite proof in $T$.

Comment: I know this works but I was trying to prove it just by using the compactness theorem.